# RewriteRule/RewriteCond help - match anything except a directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently, I have the rule

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ myFile.php?myId=$1
```

I want to be able to access a folder and its files (lets just say it's called example), and the index.php of it. However, using the rule

```
RewriteRule ^example$ example/index.php [L]
```

it instead matches the first rule. It is the first rule of the file, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your rewrite rules are executed, the `example` URL is rewritten to `example/index.php`, and then *re-enters the rewrite process* (the `[L]` flag does not prevent that). Then, your other rewrite rule matches.

So you must add an exception for `example/index.php`. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^example/index.php$ - [L]
```

which terminates the second rewrite run. Make sure to insert it above your other rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ myFile.php?myId=$1 [L]
```

This way you will get your rule match, unless request begins with '/example'. You may add extra slash, i.e. '/example/' to avoid un-matching '/example-page'.

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't exactly solve the problem, since `/example` should be rewritten to `/example/index.php`

Comment: Could you combine it with [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html)?